# stop and execute a promise javacript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, xmlhttprequest

How do I execute a HTTP request synchronously and store the result in a local object with Javascript?

Given the following javascript module:

```
var Promise = require("promise");                                                                                                                                                                       

function myReq(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status >= 400){
        console.log("got rejected");
        reject({status: xhr.status, statusText: xhr.statusText});
      } else {
        console.log("resolved");
        resolve({data: xhr.response});
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = () => {
      console.log("Error was called");
      reject({status: xhr.status, statusText: xhr.statusText});
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
}

export default myReq;
```

I want the json object from this request stored in a local variable in another script. However, when I try this code it runs it async.

```
1. import myReq from '../../lib/myReq';
2. const urlTest = "localhost://3000:/somepath";
3. const test = myReq(urlTest).then((a) => {console.log(a); return a;}).catch((b) => console.log(b));
4. console.log(test.data);
```

I want it to stop at line 3, execute the code, store the javascript object in test, and the resume execution of the rest of the code. Right now test is a Promise and test.data is undefined.

Comment: like `await myReq()`?

Comment: Why don't you use fetch?

Comment: 3. const test = await myReq(urlTest).then((a) => {console.log(a); return a;}).catch((b) => console.log(b));

This doesn't compile.

Comment: Just do `let result = await myReq(someUrl);` and then put a `try/catch` around it to catch errors.

Comment: What about the use of .then and .catch? Also, the function doesn't return anything as it operates with resolve and reject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myReq` returns a Promise, NOT just the data! That is why you need to use `then` & `catch` blocks, or alternatively use `await`.

```js
// myReq function returns a Promise, NOT a value! (Not returning 5!)
function myReq(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(5);
    }, 5000);
  });
}

// Option 1
myReq('someurl').then((data) => {
  console.log('data (option 1)', data); // You can use the data here, inside the 'then' block
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('error', error);
});

// Option 2
const run = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await myReq('someurl'); // await must be called from an 'async' function
    console.log('data (option 2)', data); // You can use the data here, inside the 'try' block
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  }
};
run();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert this to a synchronous process you can directly use the `async/await` to handle the process rather than directly moving to next step. Like you can do something like:

```
try {
const result = await myReq(url);
} catch (e) {
 // Handle error generated in the process
}
```

remember you can only `async/await` in pair means that only inside an `async` function you can use `await` keyword. For more details you can visit this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Hope this helps. Have a good day.